# Find file inside phar with symfony finder

Tags: php, symfony, phar

I have the following code to find files in a directory called robofile-templates in my source tree.
Now I am packaging the app into a phar file.

Can I use similar code to iterate over the files contained in the phar file or do I have to rewrite it?

```
protected function getTemplateRoboFiles() {
    $base = dirname( __DIR__ );

    $templates = [];

    $finder = new Finder();
    $finder->directories()->in( $base )->name( 'robofile-templates' );
    foreach ( $finder as $directory ) {
        $fileFinder = new Finder();
        $fileFinder->files()->in( $directory->getRealPath() )->name( '*.php' );
        foreach ( $fileFinder as $file ) {
            $templates[ $file->getBasename( '.php' ) ] = $file->getRealPath();
        }
    }

    return $templates;
}
```

*EDIT:* Interesting enough, `opendir` / `readdir` work inside the PHAR. I could resort to use those basic file functions, but I think Symfony file finder is built on the same basic commands?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony finder is working as expected, also finding files in phars.

My problem was on another part of the process: I was building the phar using composer install and my composer.lock was not up to data. As the file I was trying to find in the archive, was in a composer module, it was just not actually included in the phar.

So who is stumbling across this: Better check if your file is really packaged into the phar.